# What is this site?

Tags: phishing

I was reading an [article](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/05/05/chrome_origin_chip_ui_controversy/) which included an anecdote of someone who had nearly fallen for a phishing attack which:

> established a mock Halifax.co.uk website which replaced forward slashes in the legitimate URL with full stops.

By chance I wondered if there was anything at the url `http://h.alifax.co.uk` was taken and if so if it was a phishing page. However, it turns out to be a page which randomly redirects you to other seemingly random websites (I got redirected to a site comparing [diaper prices](http://www.mysupermarket.co.uk/tesco-price-comparison/Nappies/Tesco_Everyday_Value_Size_4_Maxi_7_18kg_20.html?banner=56360&utm_medium=email&utm_source=MediaBuy_UK&utm_campaign=ADNInternal&utm_content=Product&utm_term=11164808-101221543), and a travel site!).

What is this? Is there anything sinister going on at all here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website forwards you using affiliate links. They seem to have an advertising deal with all the websites they redirect to. That's not really sinister, just an attempt to get you to buy stuff you don't need, aka advertising.

Answer (score 1):

Define 'sinister'. Is the URL designed to capture your login information? No, but it can be just as bad. Imagine all those 'ad' sites filled with malware all trying to exploit vulnerabilities in your browser.

Imagine also the brand damage done by redirecting people who were hoping to reach the target they expected, and then had to slog through all that fluff.

Credential harvesting is not the only concern here.